# Select the first 2 Characters of each word on String

Tags: vb.net

I created the following function, but have not been able to finish. I want to return the first 2 characters of each word in the string.  Here is what I have so far:

```
Function SelectWords(ByVal text As String, ByVal maxWords As Integer) As String
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) Then Return String.Empty
    If maxWords <= 0 Then Return String.Empty

    Dim words As String() = text.Split(" "c)

    Return String ''I am stuck here
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not describe the purpose of maxwords, nor what to do with `a`.  The loop part:

```
Dim words = str.Split(" "c)
Dim ret As New StringBuilder    ' in case it is a long string

For Each w As String In words
    If w.Length > 1 Then
        ret.Append(w.Substring(0, 2))
    Else
        ' decide if you want 1
    End If

Next
return ret.toString
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have doesn't do anything that you describing .. Try this function instead.

```
Function SelectWords(ByVal text As String, ByVal maxWords As Integer) As String
    Dim collection As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(text, "(\w{2})\w*\b")

    Dim output As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    For Each M As Match In collection
        output.Append(M.Groups(1).Value)
        counter += 1
        If counter = maxWords Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Return output.ToString
End Function
```